# -webkit-transform and ignored z-index

Tags: html, css, safari, transform

On safari 5.1.7 for windows, some rotated elements are cutting through others elements:

[image]

While on other browsers Firefox, Chrome, IE I get:

[image]

Is there a way to avoid the 'cutting' issue on safari ?

A jsfiddle showing the issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/takuan/8473L/).

css:

```
.myFlip {
    width: 310px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    -moz-perspective: 780px;
    -webkit-perspective: 780px;
    perspective: 780px;
}
.myFlip li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: -70px;
}
.test1 {
    background-color:green;
    z-index: 30;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) scale(1.2);
    transform: rotateY(0deg) scale(1.2);
}
.test2 {
    background-color:black;
    z-index: 10;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg);
    transform: rotateY(45deg);
}
```

html:

```
<ul class="myFlip">
    <li class="test1"></li>
    <li class="test2"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the following:

By using rotateY we are adding a new dimension to our 2D classic output.
In this browser z-index don't work in 3D.

There is however a way to solve my issue:

```
.test1 {
  background-color:green;
  z-index: 30;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) scale(1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 50px);
  transform: rotateY(0deg) scale(1.2);
}
```

By applying `translate3d` to `.test1` the green and the black block are no more on the same z plan.

test1 is on the z plan where `z=50px` ( without translate3d it was on z=0px )

test2 is an 'Oblique' plan somewhere bettween `-50px<z<50px`

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, z-index does not apply to an element that does not have a 'position' attribute. [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/takuan/8473L/)

For instance :

```
position:relative;
z-index: 10;
```

I don't have a Safari browser to test it in.